# A morphism $F$ of algebraic stacks is quasi-compact iff $|F|$ is quasi-compact

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-stacks

This is 5.6.3. of Laumon, Moret-Bailly's "Champs Algeriques".

> Let $S$ be a scheme, $\mathscr{X, Y}$ algebraic stacks over $S$, and $F : \mathscr{X \to Y}$ a morphism.
> Then $F$ is quasi-compact (i.e., for every quasi-compact scheme $Y$ and every $Y \to \mathscr{Y}$, the stack $\mathscr{X} \times_\mathscr{Y} Y$ is quasi-compact) iff $|F|$ is quasi-compact.

($|F|$ is the canonical continuous map of topological spaces $|\mathscr{X}| \to |\mathscr{Y}|$.)

In this text, the authors assume that $S$ is quasi-separated and that all algebraic stacks are quasi-separated over the base scheme.
But I want to show this highlighted statement for non-qs base schemes and for non-qs algebraic stacks.

In the proof of "if" part, the authors says that, for quasi-compact algebraic stack $\mathscr{X, Y}$ and a morphism $F : \mathscr{X \to Y}$, $F$ is quasi-compact.
I think that this needs the quasi-separation of $S$ and $\mathscr{Y}$.

Taking a look at the Stacks Project, I couldn't find its references.

Is this holds for non qs stacks?
If so, how can I show it?

Comment: Can you remind us what $|F|$ is? Is it a map on coarse moduli spaces?

Comment: @DavidRoberts Thanks for pointing out. I edited it.